# Count the <a> tags inside div + childs

Tags: jquery, html, count, size, children

I have a problem regarding to jQuery. I need to count the amount of `<a>` tags within a div. Now this can easilly be done by using `$('.classOfDiv > a').size();`. But I need to count the a's within a couple of childs of classOfDiv.

Ex.

```
<div class="classOfDiv">
    <div class="div1">
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="" class="link">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$('.classOfDiv > a').size();` With the result of 12

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the [`>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) from the selector in order to get [*all*](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) `a` descendants of  `.classDiv`, not just the direct ones:

```
$(".classOfDiv a").length
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `.classOfDiv > a` selector will only get you the `<a>` tags which are direct descendants of a `<div class="classOfDiv">`, so you'll need to change your code to:

```
$('.classOfDiv a').length;
```

Notice the lack of `>` direct descendant selector.

Comment: `size()` is deprecated. You should use `length`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.classOfDiv > [class ^= "div"] > a').length
```

I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/ELMbh/)